# Go Package Cannot Find C Header Files Installed Using Homebrew on macOS

Tags: go, cgo

I am new to Go, so the answer is probably simple, but I can't figure it out.

I have installed the SoapySDR library on macOS using Homebrew. I have created a simple Go program that uses the go-soapy-sdr package which references the SoapySDR header files and also links to the SoapySDR dynamic library. Within almost all the *.go files in go-soapy-sdr are the following lines:

```
// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lSoapySDR
// #include <SoapySDR/Device.h>
...
import "C"
```

When I run `go run .` from the command line in the directory containing my program, I get
the following output:

```
# github.com/pothosware/go-soapy-sdr/pkg/device
../../pkg/mod/github.com/pothosware/go-soapy-sdr@v0.7.4/pkg/device/antenna.go:7:11: fatal error: 'SoapySDR/Device.h' file not found
 #include <SoapySDR/Device.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

so it is not finding the SoapySDR header files. And yes, they do exist; they are located at /opt/Homebrew/Cellar/soapysdr/0.8.1_1/include/SoapySDR.

Now if I change

```
// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lSoapySDR
// #include <SoapySDR/Device.h>
```

to

```
// #cgo pkg-config: soapysdr
// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
// #include <SoapySDR/Device.h>
```

then the header files are found. But since this is a third party package that has been around and in use for 5 or more years, I don't want to create my own version of it. With the change, I run into problems further down the build chain, but that is a problem for another day.

How can I use go-soapy-sdr without changes? Is there something I need to add to the go compiler call or something that needs to be added to a file in my project? I am at a stand-still with this. And no, there is no documentation with the go-soapy-sdr package that says how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add `-I/opt/Homebrew/Cellar/soapysdr/0.8.1_1/include` to the `CFLAGS` setting? Might need `-L/opt/Homebrew..../lib` on `LDFLAGS` too? I'm not sure this will help, but it's what I would try next.

Comment: Thanks for the response @aMike. Where do I add those? If it is in the go-soapy-sdr package files, then that does not work because as I stated, that is a third party package that has been in use for 5 years. There should be a way to use it without modifying the files in that package. Did you instead mean on the go command line call?

Comment: «Where do I add those?»–in those `#cgo CFLAGS` and `#cgo LDFLAGS` directives. The `-I` parameter ("i" stands for "include") is for the compiler and so should be stuck into the `CFLAGS` ("compiler flags"), and the `-L`  parameter ("l" stands for "libraries") is for the `LDFLAGS` ("linker flags").

Comment: @kostix As I said in both my original post and my comment above, go-soapy-sdr is a third party package. I do not want to have to fork my own copy of this package to make those changes since I would not be able to keep up with any future changes. There must be another way to do this.

Comment: @Jim = In the existing `#cgo LDFLAGS:`, you're telling the compiler that you want to used the external SoapySDR library. Adding the `-L/opt/Homebrew/Cellar/soapysdr/0.8.1_1/lib` is telling the compiler *where* to find it; nothing more. You're not creating your own version, you're using the files that are already installed by Homebrew. Same with adding the path to the header file to your `#cgo CFLAGS:` setting. You're telling the compiler *where* to find the include fles. Hmmm, and this is exactly what the `pkg-config` did for you... now I'm confused. :-)

Comment: @JimOrcheson, but those `#cgo` directives are in your own code, are they? BTW I'm with @aMike on it: `pkg-config` is supposed for exactly the sort of things you've used it for; I just wasn't aware it works on macosx. So to me, it looks like exactly the way to go.

Comment: @kostix No, the #cgo directives are in the go-soapy-sdr code. I have found something: I use brew to install soapysdr, but after some searching, I found instructions by pothos (the developer of SoapySDR, go-soapy-sdr, etc.) for a much more convoluted installation. Unfortunately, the instructions don't work. I will file an issue with them and maybe sometime in future I will be able to work with it on macOS. In the meantime, I have managed to get it to work on Ubuntu 22.04, so I will work on there. Thanks to you and aMike for trying to help.

Comment: @JimOrcheson I'm so sorry I missed the details that the Go settings were in soapy-sdr. I though they were in your code. You described it totally correctly, and I still missed it. I apologize for my noise.